# I can't place a call using Skype4Py API in Windows.The application goes on wait state and then call drops.

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

I have been trying to connect to Skype using Skype4Py API.All goes well until I try to call a contact.The terminal shows it is calling the designated user but the call just doesn't connect.Is it something wrong with the code or has MicroSoft discontinued the support for such third party APIs.
[Here is what I found on MicroSoft's Support page for third party APIs](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12384/how-does-my-3rd-party-application-work-with-skype-and-how-will-changes-to-skype-impact-my-3rd-party-application)

Code snippet for the same:

```
Found = False
for F in skype.Friends:
    # print F.Handle
    if F.Handle == CmdLine:
     Found = True
     print 'Calling ' + F.Handle + '..'
     skype.PlaceCall(CmdLine)
     break

if not Found:
 #    print 'Call target not found in contact list'
  sys.exit()
```

This is the output of my code:

Connecting to Skype..

Calling live:ronakshah983..

The code stops at this and call isn't connected.I have also tried replacing username with address of the user but the same problem occurs.
I have tried a lot of researching but can't figure out what is wrong.
Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution finally.The problem is that Skype has disabled all third party APIs for its latest version(version 7.x).I then installed older version(version 6.x) and disabled auto update feature in it.The same code worked on the older Skype version.

Note:Finding an older reliable version of Skype was also time consuming since they have removed all the older versions from their official website.
[Found older version on this page](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/ASUS-USB2-0-Webcam-not-recognized-by-Skype-6-18-0-106/m-p/3460911#M289818)